# table listed in sys.tables does not exist

Tags: sql-server

When I login to SSMS as sa and run the following I get one record.

```
select name from sys.tables where name ='Connote' order by name
```

However if I run

```
select * from Connote
```

I get

> Invalid object name 'Connote'.

How do I get sys.tables to contain the correct names?

The version is Standard Edition 2019 running on Linux.

Comment: Does the `AppFeature` table exist in the `sys.Tables` system catalog view?

Comment: Yes it is listed in sys.tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's in a different schema than you thought, especially if it's showing up in `sys.tables`. You can get the schema name from `sys.tables` with a query like this:

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS SchemaName, name AS TableName   
FROM sys.tables
```

Once you have the correct schema, you can try querying the table with the schema name prefixed to it, e.g. `SELECT * FROM SchemaName.AppFeature`.